# Error while running Code metrics in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am getting no managed code error while running Code metrics for solution in VS2012 for my sample program. What does this error mean?

The same can be found under-
**Analyse -> Calculate Code Metrice for solution**

`shortcut mnemonic = Alt+N -> Alt+l`

Comment: It means it's not a .NET project. Are you running it on native C++ code?

Comment: yes. I am running on CUI based C++ code.

Comment: Then that's the reason - code metrics are only available for managed code (.NET)